# Invalid format for numbers in java

Tags: java, validation

I use the following code so when the user enters an alphabet or special character in the number field, it should display an error as invalid format. When I run it, even for numbers, it is displaying as invalid format. Could someone please correct it?

```
if (!("[a-zA-Z_]+").equals(session.getObject("CLASSID")) || 
    !(" [!~`@#$]") .equals(session.getObject("CLASSID")))
{
    session.setStatusMessage("Invalid format");
    throw new AbortHandlerException();
}
```

Comment: i would rather use `matches()` for this. Something like that : `if(!((String)session.getObject("CLASSID")).matches("^[0-9]*$"))`

Comment: if i remove the ! its not displaying any error message for alphabets as well

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I think you are confusing regex pattern matching with Java string equality. Your code above is checking whether the string from the session is equal to a pattern. As I understand it, you are trying to determine whether a string contains a number or not?

There are a number of ways you can do that. One such method is to use a regex `\d` match. Or a Guava lib `com.google.common.base.CharMatcher#digit`

Or simply try to parse the number and catch a `java.text.ParseException` if it fails. The latter might widely be considered bad practice as it's an anti pattern known as using exceptions for flow control.

here are some examples:

## Guava

```
CharMatcher.inRange('0', '9').matchesAllOf("A string");
```

## Regex

```
final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher("0292");
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        // contains number
    } else {
        // no number.
    }
```

The double backslash is to escape the `\` character in Java.

Of course there are other basic examples, as pointed out by other contributors before me such as plain old `Integer.parse`, `Long.parse`, `new BigInteger("")` Just remember again to catch the exceptions in case of parse error.